# django shell conditional expression if

Tags: django, shell

```
>>> items=SomeModelClass.objects.all()
>>> for item in items:
...     print(item.status)
...     if(item.status == "New"):
...             print("New Item")
...     else:
...             print("Something else")
...
New
Something else
Case Closed
Something else
```

Here, a simple if else code is executed in a django shell., Though there is a item.status by value "New", the result is always false. What causes this code to fail?

Comment: Are you sure that item.status is actually a string ? 
However this question has nothing to do with Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check `print(type(item.status)` returns a string.

Ensure that you typecast different datatypes before comparing with equality operator.

Comment: useful suggestion; The things compated were <class 'app.models.Status'> and a String